Exposing sins anonymously
I want to write a sort of autobiography describing my life as a revert to Islam and the struggles I’ve had growing up etc.,but I know that it is haram to expose my sins or the sins of others so I’m thinking if I were to use aliases for everyone I include in the book and for myself and publish it anonymously as well as use a different name and probably not to tell anyone that it was me who wrote it would this be permissible and was also thinking if I was to publish it could I label it as fiction or non-fiction due to using alias’s or label it as “based on real events” and admit that its a true story but with different names.
Sorry if this question is really long I just wanna make sure. And should I get people's permission to write about them even if I don’t use their name.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].
